# Cannot post to osticket with ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I am using osTicket on a subdomain of my domain. I have copied the open ticket form exactly from osTicket and placed it on a page on my main domain. It posts through to the subdomain and works fine and the ticket is created. If I try and do exactly the same post with ajax though I get no response. It posts the variables exactly the same and finds the script but the script returns no output.

Any help very much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents this for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working:
if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['action']) && ($HTTP_POST_VARS['action'] == 'process')) {
        define('CWD', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/support/" );
        chdir( CWD );
        require_once('client.inc.php');

```
    $inName    =  tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['name']);
    $inEmail   =  tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['email']);
    $inPhone   =  tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['phone']);
    $inTopic=1;
    $inSubject =  tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['subject']);
    $inMessage =  tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['message']);
    define('SOURCE','Web'); //Ticket source.
    require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.ticket.php');
    $errors=ARRAY();
    $post_data['topicId']  =  $inTopic;
    $post_data['deptId']   =  0;
    $post_data['emailId']  =  0;
    $post_data['a']        =  'open';
    $post_data['draft_id'] =  50;
    $post_data['email']    = $inEmail;
    $post_data['name']     = $inName;
    $post_data['phone']    = $inPhone;
    $post_data['subject']  = $inSubject;
    $post_data['message']  = $inMessage;
    $ticket=Ticket::create($post_data, $errors, SOURCE);
```

//      tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, '', 'SSL'));
  }